# Right margin in the lecture notes

Tags: margins, books

I would like to write a lecture notes for the students in such a manner that the right margin is devoted for the self notes as shown in the attached file. How can I do this? The help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Isn't just leaving a margin sufficient? If you have this "Put your own notes" it does in fact occupy space for a possible note. :)

Comment: I believe beamer has a built in feature (page 196).

Comment: What have you tried? It's a waste of time if someone suggests what you have already done. --- GOM